# how to read file and return string and its value

Tags: java, string, file, return

i have file containing words and its value. i want to create parameters that returns the words and its value but I'm not sure how to do this and my code doesn't work.

this is my code;

```
public static void main(String[] args)throws IOException {

    Scanner scan = new Scanner("/..../file.txt");
    String word = scan.next();

    while(scan.hasNextLine()){
        scan.nextLine();
        System.out.println(word);

    }

    scan.close(); 



}
```

this is what is in the file, there are lots of data;

```
{hi=2, bye=5, school=3, went=2, going=1, yesss=1, etc..}
```

any help on how to do this please?

Comment: Java? You should tag the correct language for your question. Also, I suggest that you remove consecutive blank lines to make the code easier to read.

Comment: What about your code isn't working? Can you show us the output, or any exceptions?

Comment: @crashmstr yes sorry its java. its basically returning my file path i.e. /..../file.txt which i don't understand why

Comment: what is there in your file? are values comma sep? or they are present at new line?

Answer (score 1):

The scanner class scans the value provided in the constructor.
If that value is a string it simply scans that string.

If you want it to scan a file you should use a file object as the argument e.g.:

Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File("/..../file.txt"));

Answer (score 0):

try doing following

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    BufferedReader br = null;
    try {
        String sCurrentLine;
        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("D:/abc.txt"));

        while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
            String trimmedStr = sCurrentLine.replace(" ", "");
            String mainStr = trimmedStr.substring(1,trimmedStr.length()-1);
            String[] arr = mainStr.split(",");
            Map<String, String> mainMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
            for(String pair : arr){
                String[] kvArr = pair.split("=");
                mainMap.put(kvArr[0], kvArr[1]);
            }
            System.out.println(mainMap.get("hi"));
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            if (br != null)br.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

your file should contain following

> {hi=2, bye=5, school=3, went=2, going=1, yesss=1}

OP:

> 2

Comment: this looks good but my file contains hundreds of words and their values, if i want to get all of them, how do i do this in a easier way than having to repeat the printout process

Comment: paste some of ur file content in proper format as i did in your question

Comment: edited my question, this is how its shown in my file

Comment: any possibility of you commenting the code. so i can understand what its doing, thanks

Comment: well you can print different things like "trimmedStr", "mainStr" to understand, that will help you understand more than I am explaining things

Answer (score 0):

The way you pass you are passing your file path in Scanner constructor is wrong ,you can pass your file path in this way

Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File("/..../file.txt"));

hope this may help .